# Can multiple browser tabs share a piece of javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, notifications

Consider the following JavaScript code:

```
var timer = setInterval(getNotifications, 10000);

function getNotifications() {
  $.ajax('/notifications/dashboard.js', {dataType: 'script'});
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is grab a collection of notifications that have not been "growled". (see [jQuery Growl](http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/) for more info on what a growl is...)

This is working fairly well with one tab, but a user may have multiple tabs open. I've been trying to research how Facebook might handle so many pull requests from so many open tabs and I'm not finding any 1000ft views on this, only 30,000ft architecture views which are not that helpful.

What I'm wondering is, can I have one copy of that code above for all my tabs? I just need the browser itself to hit this JavaScript once for all tabs and growl (the growl is in the JavaScript response) for each tab that is open using the same data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with growl, but have you considered placing your growl response in localStorage to access it from all tabs?

Comment: It's pretty cool, check out the link I provided in my op. Mike, thanks I will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

First I would add the script to both pages with

`<script src="myScript.js"<>/script>`

For data:

HTML Local Storage should be what you are looking for . Here is a link to know more -http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Also you could use window.name known as JavaScript session. But it only works as long as the
same window/tab is used. Link - http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html

Plus there are cookies obviously.